# quietly eval quietly vsim still echoes

Tags: tcl, vhdl, modelsim

I am running modelsim simulations using tcl scripting and I want to turn off all modelsim echoes to the transcript window except my own "puts" statements.

a for loop in my tcl script runs the command: `eval vsim $vsim_opt work.my_top_level.vhd` but this causes modelsim to echo the vsim command..

I've also tried running: `quietly eval quietly vsim $vsim_opt work.my_top_level.vhd` but still it echoes.

when I run a dummy tcl command in modelsim command line: `quietly eval expr 2+2` 
it works... no echo... what gives?

I am using modelsim PE 10.1c

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tcl Expect package.  This will allow you to selectively log what you want from the transcript or just run your simulation.

Try

```
package require Expect
log_user 0
spawn vsim $vsim_opt work.my_top_level.vhd
log_user 1
```